# HTML on image not printing in pdf

Tags: php, html, mpdf

This is my code

```
<?php
class Diagram
{
function outLet()
{
    $boothsizer = 3;

    if($boothsizer ==  3){
        $cellWidth = '112px';
        $cellHeight = '52px';
        $innerDivElectricTop = '41px'; 
        $innerDivElectricLeft = '110px';    
        $backgroundImage = 'url(booth_top_images/5X20TOP.jpg)';
        $width = '900px';
        $height = '225px';
        $sidewalls = 2;
        $backwalls = 6; 
    }
    else
    if($boothsizer ==  19)
    {
        $cellWidth = '144px';
        $cellHeight = '145px';
        $innerDivElectricTop = '105px'; 
        $innerDivElectricLeft =  '73px';    
        $backgroundImage = 'url(booth_top_images/10X10TOP.jpg)';
        $width = '599px';
        $height = '605px';
        $sidewalls = 3;
        $backwalls = 3;
    }

    $innerDivElectricWidth = $backwalls * $cellWidth;
    $innerDivElectricHeight = $sidewalls * $cellHeight;

    $output = '<div style="width:'.$width.'; height:'.$height.'; background-image:'.$backgroundImage.'">';

    $output .= '<div id="inner_div_electric" style="position: relative; top: '.$innerDivElectricTop.'; left: '.$innerDivElectricLeft.';width:'.$innerDivElectricWidth.';height:'.$innerDivElectricHeight.'">';

    for($i=1; $i<=$sidewalls; $i++)
    {
            for($j=1; $j<=$backwalls; $j++)
            {
                $output .= '<span class="droppable_class" style="width:'.($cellWidth-2).'; height:'.($cellHeight-2).'; border:1px solid red; float:left;display:inline-block;margin:0px;padding:0px;"></span>';

            }
    }

    $output .= '</div></div>';

    echo $output;


    include("test/mpdf/mpdf.php");
    $mpdf=new mPDF();   
    $mpdf->ignore_invalid_utf8 = true;
    $stylesheet = file_get_contents('appstyle_pdf.css');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($output);

    $comname = "vam";

    $name = "test/generated_pdfs/".str_replace(" ","-",$comname).".pdf";      
    $mpdf->Output($name,"F");   


}
}

$diag = new Diagram;
print $diag->outLet();
?>
```

In my code I am trying to generate some squares upon images and trying to generate a pdf, when I echoed the $output I can see squares on images, but in my generated pdf only the image is printing, squares are not?

Anybody any ideas???

Comment: could you please add debug functionality to see the error and edit it?
`$mpdf->debug = true;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `<span>` tags to `<div>` tags and it should work.

Unfortunately I don't have any explaination for the solution at the moment. According the mpdf script `<span>` tags are part of the `enabledtags` collection - mpdf.php Line 23249. So I'm not totally sure why `<div>` works and `<span>` doesn't.

Comment: I was able to generate squares also, but the width and heights are not working in pdf.